# Induction proof of $\sum_{i=1}^n i^3 = \frac{n^2(n+1)^2}{4}$

Tags: discrete-mathematics

$$\sum_{i=1}^n i^3 = \frac{n^2(n+1)^2}{4}$$

How do you prove this by induction? How can I approach this, or maybe give me an answer and show me how you did this in detail? Would really appreciate your help, Thanks

Comment: Try searching on the site (or Google) for "sum of first $n$ cubes".

Comment: @GitGud, One of the commonest Question here

Answer (score 1):

**Steps**

- Verify the equality for $n=1$
- Assume we have the equality for some $n\ge1$
- Now for $n+1$ we have
  $$\sum_{i=1}^{n+1}i^3=\sum_{i=1}^{n}i^3+(n+1)^3=n^2(n+1)^2/4+(n+1)^3=(n+1)^2\left[\underbrace{n^2+4n+4}_{=(n+2)^2}\right]/4$$
- Conclude.

Answer (score 0):

Hint/Very Sketchy Sketch of the Proof: Let $S(n) = \sum_{i=1}^n i^3$. You wish to show that $S(n) = n^2(n+1)^2/4$ using induction. The most obvious route is to induct on $n$.

**Base Case**: Is $S(1) = 1^2(1+1)^2/4$?

**Inductive Hypothesis:** Assume $S(n) = n^2(n+1)^2/4$ for some $n$.

You then need to show that $S(n+1) = (n+1)^2(n+2)^2/4$. To do this, you need to find a relationship between $S(n)$ and $S(n+1)$. Do you see how to write $S(n+1)$ in terms of $S(n)$?